# Renderizar uma quantidade passada por props para um Componente

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Como posso renderizar uma quantidade de elemento passada por props para o Componente?

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cards amount={4}></Cards>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```js
function Cards(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {/* Aqui quero renderizar a quantidade de tds que passei na propriedade 'props.amount', algo como um loop.  */}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Danilo, nessa situação, o que faz mais sentido seria em si passar uma lista de objetos para essa props e renderizá-la depois, em vez de passar um número (amount). Dessa forma, você passa uma lista de cards como parâmetro, e depois mostra cada card quando você for percorrer a lista, então ficaria mais ou menos :

```js
//App.js

function App() {

  const cards = [
    {
      id: 0,
      titulo: 'Card 0',
      descricao: 'Este é um card',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      titulo: 'Card 1',
      descricao: 'Este é outro card',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      titulo: 'Card 2',
      descricao: 'Este é o último card',
    },
  ]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Cards cards={cards}></Cards>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```js
//Cards.js

function Cards(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {props.cards.map((card) => (
          <tr key={card.id}>
            <td>{card.titulo}</td>
            <td>{card.descricao}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

Estou supondo que você queira fazer dessa maneira, mas se você realmente quiser passar um `amount` como parâmetro e mostrar uma lista com esse tamanho que você passou, da pra utilizar um `Array(props.amount).map`:

```js
function Cards(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {Array(props.amount).map(() => (
          <tr>
            <td>Card</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

export default Cards
```